# Override react-multiselect-checkboxes styling

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-multiselect-checkboxes

I'm using [react-multiselect-checkboxes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multiselect-checkboxes) in my project.

The problem is with changing it's styling, the css classes in inspect mode have these values: `.css-1r4vtzz` and `.css-48ayfv`.

If I'm adding them in css file and override a property with !important it seems to work.

But If I add another class to that element, for example in my React app:

`className="new-css-rule css-1r4vtzz"` - it doesn't take into acoount the new class, even if the styling is with !important. It doesn't even show the class's name in inspect mode.

Is there a way to add that new css class and use its styling?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

> Like props, styles supported by react-select are passed directly into
> the underlying Select component. Some of the defaults have been
> tweaked for the multiselect, but you can override them like normal

There are several methods of overriding the styling. They can be found [here](https://react-select.com/styles).